# Different font-family for two different parts of the same string

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element, font-family

```
.my-link::after {
    content: "text \2661";
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Looking at the code above I need to set the font-family for the content of the pseudo element.That's wouldn't be a problem.

But I need to set the font-family for the **text** part to Arial and the font family for the **\2661** part to Helvetica.

Basically two different font-families for different parts of the same string.

**Is there any way to achieve this with only CSS or Sass?**

Otherwise I can just think of setting the font-family for the whole content of the pseudo element via CSS to Arial and then write a JavaScript function, which goes through the string inside the content of the pseudo element, find the **\2661** part and changes its font-family to Helvetica.

Any suggestions, idea, hints etc would be appreciated.

Comment: consider both pseudo element, or the other one is already in use?

Comment: JS won't reach into pseudo's so you won't be able to interact with it as you've described.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of before & after to achieve this. Ensure that the pseudos are floating right and they'll end up looking like they're both appearing after the link.

https://jsfiddle.net/zxwkjmt3/

This works assuming your links are `display:inline-block;`

```css
.my-link {
  display: inline-block;
}

.my-link::before {
    content: '\2661';
    float: right;
    font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
.my-link::after {
    content: 'text';
    float: right;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="my-link">Link</a>
```

Edit: It's worth noting, avoid thinking of pseudo's as nested elements, they are not. They'll give with a little extra flexibility but they're limited in what you can do, if possible nesting actual elements gives you the most flexibility.