# How to use multiple fonts in js string?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I achieve multiple family-fonts in one string in javascript

JS:

```
    function formatTime (diff1) {
       var m = pad(parseInt(diff1/60))
       var diff = diff1-(m*60);
       var s = pad(diff);
            return m +":"+ s + "/" + "20";    
}
```

I want the "/" to have a different font-family than the other parts of the string who are using the font of the class in the html file:

```
<div class="timer2" id="demo"></div>
```

how can I achieve this?

I want to use a font that I imported to my css file.

I want it to look like this

[good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYmoF.png)

instead of this:

[bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoBgB.png)

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56670370/different-font-family-for-two-different-parts-of-the-same-string) help you?

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? It’s hard to tell what you intend because you’re using single character variables. What does formatTime have to do with fonts?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have fonts. It's just computer code. However, you can display text in a browser through HTML and CSS, and there you can change the font

Comment: @mikemaccana I edited my post so you know what I mean

Comment: I’m on mobile but this is a css question. You want three spans, before the slash, the slash, and after the slash. Use a different class for the slash span with the narrower font.

Comment: You can wrap the / in its own element with its own class having a different font family. Example for built in tag like this would tbe the `<code>` tag

Comment: @mikemaccana yes but how do I use different class for the slash?

Comment: @TheFool how can I do this in js?

Comment: precisely like the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the HTML of the `#demo` element and convert the `'/'` to a `<span class="sep" />` element and declare some styles for the `.sep` class.

```js
const pad = s => (s + '').padStart(2, '0');

const formatTime = diff1 => {
  const m = pad(parseInt(diff1 / 60))
  const diff = diff1 - (m * 60);
  const s = pad(diff);
  return `${m}:${s}<span class="sep"></span>20`;
}

const demo = document.querySelector('#demo');
let time = 0;

const update = () => {
  demo.innerHTML = formatTime(time);
  time++;
};

update();
setInterval(update, 1000);
```

```css
#demo {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.sep {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.sep::after {
  content: '/';
}
```

```html
<div class="timer2" id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: can you also do this in plain js?

Comment: This will make window.demo due to the ID

Comment: @likesum this is "plain js"

Comment: @mikemaccana using `window.<ID>` is [not recommended...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994139/why-windowid-document-getelementbyid-id) It was an asinine thing introduced by IE.

Comment: Yes @Mr.Polywhirl that is exactly what my comment is saying. Why are you addressing me?

Comment: @mikemaccana you commented saying, _**"This will make window.demo due to the ID"**_. You directed it at me. I was replying, saying that this is BAD practice. I linked you to a thread explaining why it is a bad idea to access elements by their ID from the `window`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes. I pointed out a bad practice in your code. I am not sure why you are addressing me if you agree.

Comment: @mikemaccana wait, what is bad practice about my code? I never used `window.demo`, I created a global variable called `demo` by retrieving it by ID. This is the proper way.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl you created `window.demo` with `<div class="timer2" id="demo">`. That's the antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

We just have a different class for the `/` character:

```html
<div class="time">
  12
  <span class="divider">/</span>
  23
</div>
```

```css
.time {
  font-family: "something";
}

.divider {
  font-family: "something-different";
}
```

[Here's a working JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejcxmfn9/)

You don't need JS here. Fonts are normally controlled by CSS, not JS.